# Stephen Cleary Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding- not working when executed from Command or properety setter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have spent my relaxed weekend playing around with the pattern suggested by Stephen Cleary:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Dn605875.aspx

As it works very fine in the example application, I havent seen it working when used in a Viewmodel method called from a ICommand bound to a Button.

```
        public NotifyTaskCompletion<int> Length { get; set; }

    private readonly ICommand _simpleCommand;
    public ICommand SimpleCommand
    {
        get { return _simpleCommand; }
    }      

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _simpleCommand = new RelayCommand(Method);
    }

    public void Method(object o)
    {
        Length = new NotifyTaskCompletion<int>(MyStaticService.CountBytesInUrlAsync("http://www.example.com"));
    }
```

I've worked with a lot of debugging, and I can see that the PropertyChanged event is null when used as described above. If the same method **Method** is invoked from the constructor of the viewmodel, everything works fine.

```
public sealed class NotifyTaskCompletion<TResult> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public NotifyTaskCompletion(Task<TResult> task)
    {
        Task = task;
        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            var _ = WatchTaskAsync(task);
        }
    }
    private async Task WatchTaskAsync(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        // ReSharper disable once EmptyGeneralCatchClause
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged == null)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Please let me know if anyone has an idea of the differences between the two scenarios.

Comment: is that the entire code for NotifyTaskCompletion class? Looks like it's not raising the NotifyPropertyChanged event (when the one in the article is). This may explain why it works in the ctor (one time binding during setting of the datacontext) and not after the datacontext has been set (since the property is changed, it will need to raise the notifypropertychanged event)

Comment: Ahhh - I found it - very embarrasing....

    NotifyPropertyChanged("Length");

was missing after the call to the Service.